# Как подключить PyCharm к Python?

Tags: python, pycharm

У меня уже был установлен пайчарм и пайтон, создано немало проэктов, но случайно удалил сам пайтон.
Вот сам вопрос. Как через внутренние настройки пайчарма добавить путь к пайтону(он установлен в новой папке)?

Comment: в настройках вкладка project interpreter, там путь указать

Answer (score 1):

Вот [ссылка](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html) на документацию JetBrains:

> В правом нижнем углу ткнуть в Status Bar на Python и там выбрать
>   нужный ИЛИ перейти в File / Settings и там выбрать Project
>   Interpreter. В нем уже выбрать нужное окружение или указать адрес
>   системного (System Interpreter).